# FirebaseStorageUI SDWebImage cache image with custom key

Tags: swift, firebase, sdwebimage

I want to cache image with a custom key, so that whenever the image will be updated in the same URL I am able to handle it and re-download the image instead of getting it from the cache.

In my Android app the cache key is: 'path'+'image_update_timestamp'

In the iOS app I have:

`imageView.sd_setImage(with: reference, placeholderImage: nil)`

Is there a way to do something like that in iOS too?